# How to make Haskell use another list depending on the previous answer in Haskell

Tags: haskell, optimization

I am doing project euler question 63 where I must find the amount of numbers that exist where:

```
x^(n) == y
```

Where `n` is the length of `y`.

It soon emerges that the results for this condition alternate between odd and even and so I came up with this in Haskell:

```
prob63 = [ n | n <- nums n , i <-[1..10], i^(length $ show n) == n]

nums n | odd (n) == True = filter odd [n..]
    | otherwise         = filter even [n..]
```

If n <- [1..], prob63 produces a stream that looks like this:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,125,216,343,512,729,1296,2401,4096,6561,16807,32768,59049,117649,262144,531441]
```

But this is slow and what I came up with after doesn't work. What I need is, depending on the previous answer, it will start testing the odd or even integers from `n`. How would I go about this from what I already have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look again at the output. The elements **do not** alternate between odd and even!

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,125,216,343,512,729,1296,2401,4096,6561,16807,32768,59049,117649,262144,531441]
```

---

I noticed this after implementing the code that you ask for. Its output does not match the output of your code. I'll post the code here anyway:

```
prob63 :: [Integer]
prob63 = test 1
  where
    test s = next : test (next + 1)
      where
        next = head [n | n <- [s,s+2..], i <-[1..10], i^(length $ show n) == n]
```

Comment: could it be that that single pair is just an abnormal case?

Comment: Nope, there's another one, as you can see: 59049,117649. Also, perhaps you should iterate over the base and power (instead of over the power and *n*), and determine the upper bound for both. There is a very fast solution to this problem.

Comment: Also, it seems at this stage of learning Haskell, I know what needs to be done, it is just quite often the case that I don't know how to implement it. I thought of an optimisation wherein, it begins searching for the next value of n, that is `(current n) + (difference between current and previous )`